# Circulate a 2d array using bresenham line algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, math, raster, bresenham

I at the moment trying to draw some angled lines using bresenham line algorithm which can circulate a 2d array of size 21x21, as a line angled from 0 - 2pi.

[lines from bresenham](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdXHf.png)

So the idea is that the program has to output the values which the lines pass through in the grid..

So an example with 5x5

```
Angle:0
     _ _ _ _ _ 
    |_|_|_|_|_|
    |_|_|_|_|_|
    |_|_|.|.|.|
    |_|_|_|_|_|
    |_|_|_|_|_|

Angle: 45
     _ _ _ _ _ 
    |_|_|_|_|.|
    |_|_|_|.|_|
    |_|_|.|_|_|
    |_|_|_|_|_|
    |_|_|_|_|_|
```

and so on..

The problem here is that it doesn't look like that my program does that.. The endpoint lies within the given radius length..

I am sure that I am messing up with the math.. So i hope some of you could help me here..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
typedef std::pair<int,int> coordinate;

int sign(double x ){ return (x > 0) ? 1 : ((x < 0) ? -1 : 0); }

coordinate endpoint(double angle, int x1 , int y1, int lenght)
{
    double radians = (M_PI/180)*angle;

    double x2 = x1 + (lenght * cos(radians));
    double y2 = y1 + (lenght * sin(radians));

    return std::make_pair(round(x2),round(y2));
}

void bresenham(coordinate start, coordinate end)
{
    //restriction a.x < b.x  and 0 < H/W < 1
    int y =  start.second;
    int w = end.first - start.first;
    int h = end.second - start.second;
    int f = 2*h-w; // current error term

    for (int x = start.first; x<= end.first; x++)
    {
        cout << "mark: " << x << "," << y << endl;
        if (f < 0)
        {
            f = f + 2*h;
        }
        else
        {
            y++;
            f=f+2*(h-w);
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    coordinate start = make_pair(0,0);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 45; i++)
    {
        coordinate end = endpoint(i,0,0,10);
        cout << "    endPos: "<< "(" << end.first <<","  << end.second   <<")"    << " Angle: " << i << "       " << endl;
        cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;
        bresenham(start, end);
        cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output.

```
    endPos: (10,0) Angle: 0       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,0
mark: 3,0
mark: 4,0
mark: 5,0
mark: 6,0
mark: 7,0
mark: 8,0
mark: 9,0
mark: 10,0
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,0) Angle: 1       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,0
mark: 3,0
mark: 4,0
mark: 5,0
mark: 6,0
mark: 7,0
mark: 8,0
mark: 9,0
mark: 10,0
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,0) Angle: 2       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,0
mark: 3,0
mark: 4,0
mark: 5,0
mark: 6,0
mark: 7,0
mark: 8,0
mark: 9,0
mark: 10,0
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,1) Angle: 3       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,0
mark: 3,0
mark: 4,0
mark: 5,1
mark: 6,1
mark: 7,1
mark: 8,1
mark: 9,1
mark: 10,1
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,1) Angle: 4       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,0
mark: 3,0
mark: 4,0
mark: 5,1
mark: 6,1
mark: 7,1
mark: 8,1
mark: 9,1
mark: 10,1
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,1) Angle: 5       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,0
mark: 3,0
mark: 4,0
mark: 5,1
mark: 6,1
mark: 7,1
mark: 8,1
mark: 9,1
mark: 10,1
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,1) Angle: 6       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,0
mark: 3,0
mark: 4,0
mark: 5,1
mark: 6,1
mark: 7,1
mark: 8,1
mark: 9,1
mark: 10,1
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,1) Angle: 7       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,0
mark: 3,0
mark: 4,0
mark: 5,1
mark: 6,1
mark: 7,1
mark: 8,1
mark: 9,1
mark: 10,1
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,1) Angle: 8       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,0
mark: 3,0
mark: 4,0
mark: 5,1
mark: 6,1
mark: 7,1
mark: 8,1
mark: 9,1
mark: 10,1
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,2) Angle: 9       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,0
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,1
mark: 5,1
mark: 6,1
mark: 7,1
mark: 8,2
mark: 9,2
mark: 10,2
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,2) Angle: 10       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,0
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,1
mark: 5,1
mark: 6,1
mark: 7,1
mark: 8,2
mark: 9,2
mark: 10,2
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,2) Angle: 11       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,0
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,1
mark: 5,1
mark: 6,1
mark: 7,1
mark: 8,2
mark: 9,2
mark: 10,2
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,2) Angle: 12       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,0
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,1
mark: 5,1
mark: 6,1
mark: 7,1
mark: 8,2
mark: 9,2
mark: 10,2
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,2) Angle: 13       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,0
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,1
mark: 5,1
mark: 6,1
mark: 7,1
mark: 8,2
mark: 9,2
mark: 10,2
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,2) Angle: 14       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,0
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,1
mark: 5,1
mark: 6,1
mark: 7,1
mark: 8,2
mark: 9,2
mark: 10,2
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,3) Angle: 15       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,1
mark: 5,2
mark: 6,2
mark: 7,2
mark: 8,2
mark: 9,3
mark: 10,3
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,3) Angle: 16       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,1
mark: 5,2
mark: 6,2
mark: 7,2
mark: 8,2
mark: 9,3
mark: 10,3
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,3) Angle: 17       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,1
mark: 5,2
mark: 6,2
mark: 7,2
mark: 8,2
mark: 9,3
mark: 10,3
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (10,3) Angle: 18       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,1
mark: 5,2
mark: 6,2
mark: 7,2
mark: 8,2
mark: 9,3
mark: 10,3
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (9,3) Angle: 19       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,1
mark: 5,2
mark: 6,2
mark: 7,2
mark: 8,3
mark: 9,3
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (9,3) Angle: 20       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,1
mark: 5,2
mark: 6,2
mark: 7,2
mark: 8,3
mark: 9,3
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (9,4) Angle: 21       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,2
mark: 5,2
mark: 6,3
mark: 7,3
mark: 8,4
mark: 9,4
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (9,4) Angle: 22       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,2
mark: 5,2
mark: 6,3
mark: 7,3
mark: 8,4
mark: 9,4
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (9,4) Angle: 23       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,2
mark: 5,2
mark: 6,3
mark: 7,3
mark: 8,4
mark: 9,4
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (9,4) Angle: 24       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,2
mark: 5,2
mark: 6,3
mark: 7,3
mark: 8,4
mark: 9,4
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (9,4) Angle: 25       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,2
mark: 5,2
mark: 6,3
mark: 7,3
mark: 8,4
mark: 9,4
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (9,4) Angle: 26       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,0
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,1
mark: 4,2
mark: 5,2
mark: 6,3
mark: 7,3
mark: 8,4
mark: 9,4
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (9,5) Angle: 27       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,2
mark: 4,2
mark: 5,3
mark: 6,3
mark: 7,4
mark: 8,4
mark: 9,5
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (9,5) Angle: 28       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,2
mark: 4,2
mark: 5,3
mark: 6,3
mark: 7,4
mark: 8,4
mark: 9,5
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (9,5) Angle: 29       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,2
mark: 4,2
mark: 5,3
mark: 6,3
mark: 7,4
mark: 8,4
mark: 9,5
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (9,5) Angle: 30       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,2
mark: 4,2
mark: 5,3
mark: 6,3
mark: 7,4
mark: 8,4
mark: 9,5
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (9,5) Angle: 31       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,2
mark: 4,2
mark: 5,3
mark: 6,3
mark: 7,4
mark: 8,4
mark: 9,5
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (8,5) Angle: 32       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,2
mark: 4,3
mark: 5,3
mark: 6,4
mark: 7,4
mark: 8,5
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (8,5) Angle: 33       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,1
mark: 3,2
mark: 4,3
mark: 5,3
mark: 6,4
mark: 7,4
mark: 8,5
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (8,6) Angle: 34       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,2
mark: 3,2
mark: 4,3
mark: 5,4
mark: 6,5
mark: 7,5
mark: 8,6
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (8,6) Angle: 35       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,2
mark: 3,2
mark: 4,3
mark: 5,4
mark: 6,5
mark: 7,5
mark: 8,6
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (8,6) Angle: 36       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,2
mark: 3,2
mark: 4,3
mark: 5,4
mark: 6,5
mark: 7,5
mark: 8,6
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (8,6) Angle: 37       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,2
mark: 3,2
mark: 4,3
mark: 5,4
mark: 6,5
mark: 7,5
mark: 8,6
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (8,6) Angle: 38       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,2
mark: 3,2
mark: 4,3
mark: 5,4
mark: 6,5
mark: 7,5
mark: 8,6
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (8,6) Angle: 39       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,2
mark: 3,2
mark: 4,3
mark: 5,4
mark: 6,5
mark: 7,5
mark: 8,6
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (8,6) Angle: 40       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,2
mark: 3,2
mark: 4,3
mark: 5,4
mark: 6,5
mark: 7,5
mark: 8,6
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (8,7) Angle: 41       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,2
mark: 3,3
mark: 4,4
mark: 5,4
mark: 6,5
mark: 7,6
mark: 8,7
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (7,7) Angle: 42       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,2
mark: 3,3
mark: 4,4
mark: 5,5
mark: 6,6
mark: 7,7
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (7,7) Angle: 43       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,2
mark: 3,3
mark: 4,4
mark: 5,5
mark: 6,6
mark: 7,7
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (7,7) Angle: 44       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,2
mark: 3,3
mark: 4,4
mark: 5,5
mark: 6,6
mark: 7,7
--------------------------------------------
    endPos: (7,7) Angle: 45       
--------------------------------------------
mark: 0,0
mark: 1,1
mark: 2,2
mark: 3,3
mark: 4,4
mark: 5,5
mark: 6,6
mark: 7,7
--------------------------------------------
```

What am i doing wrong?... I know that the bresenham algorithm might have to be modified to overcome slopes greater 1 and lower that 0.

**--Update Clarify the problem --**

I am trying the iterate the 2d array in a circular manner, using bresenham line algorithm .

The algorithm should start from the center of the 2d array, and "shoot out" a beam at angles between 0 - 2pi. The beam has to start from the center and end at the edge of the matrix, Hope it makes more sense..

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|

 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|.|.|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|.|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|.|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|.|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|.|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```

Comment: Why do you think that you're doing something wrong? The output looks reasonable as far as I can see. Of course, I couldn't check every number...

Comment: Each output should contain 10 data points..  hence the length = 10. 
but the output from Angle 0 to  angle 17 has 11 data points.. and from angle 32 to 45 contains less than 10 data points..

Which is why, it does do as it suppose to do..

Comment: No, that's absolutely fine. There are 11 points from `(0, 0)` to `(10, 0)`. If you have a very shallow angle, you proceed by the pixel's side length. If your angle is 45°, you proceed by the pixel's diagonal, which is longer. Hence, you need fewer pixels when going diagonally to reach the same radius.

Comment: hmmm... but that doesn't solve my problem of only taking elements from the center and  all element placed at a certain angle...

Comment: Maybe you want to sample the target points on the square surrounding rather than on a circle?

Comment: i want to sample the points which the line intersect in matrix.. hope the addition makes it more clear..

Comment: Then don't use a circle to generate the target points. Walk along the matrix border.

Comment: how about the angle ?... and would your solution be like..

Comment: @J.Down Am I correct assuming `(0,0)` is middle of your matrix not the corner?  if not then you should also set `x1,y1` to middle of the matrix ...

Comment: (0,0) is the middle of my matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **You have Bresenham only for first Octant `(dx>=0,dy>=0,dx>=dy)`**

   so when you use angles outside `<0,45>` degrees it will not work properly. You have more option to solve this:

   - use 8 branches each with own interpolation `( dx>=0, dx<0 combined with dy>=0, dy<0)`
   - use 2 branches `( |dx|>=|dy|, |dx|<|dy| )` here instead of `x++,y++,x--,y--` use `x+=sx,y+=sy` instead where `sx,sy` is the step direction precomputed before interpolation. (in **asm** auto modifiable constants are usually used but in **C/C++** you need variables for this)

   Do not forget to use as **main interpolation axis** the one with **bigger absolute change** So if `(|dx|>=|dy|)` the main axis is `x` which means `x` is (dec)incremented in each `for` pass and the `y` only in the `if` statement...
2. **endpoint is wrong**

   As Nico Schertler pointed out the endpoints are wrong. Use as radius the bigger half size of your matrix and change the bresenham interpolation to stop when `x` or `y` gets out of range of matrix ...

   Another option is to set major axis to edge of matrix (depends on the octants) and compute the second axis via `sin` or `cos` (it is `90` degree triangle)

Comment: I am not sure what you meant with the bigger half..  (0,0) i the centrum of the matrix..  and therefore are each half has the same length..